# Querying a complex nested dictionary with duplicate entries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm essentially writing a program that will automatically generate a pdf using information from a given nested dictionary. I have searched extensively and cannot find a method that both suits my needs and is easy to grok from an outside perspective. My main problem and question is:

> Using a nested dictionary where some keys have multiple values, how do
>   I fully extract the relevant information in a sequential manner?

To demonstrate the issue and goal, I'll illustrate with the following nested dictionary I used in a previous question:

```
{'Earth': 
    {'Northern Hemisphere': 
        {'North America': 
            {'The United States of America': 
                {'California': 'Sacramento', 
                 'Kentucky': 'Frankfurt', 
                 'Colorado': 'Denver', 
                 'Oregon': 'Salem', 
                 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 
                 'Nevada': 'Carson City'
                 }
            }
        },
            {'Canada':
                {'Ontario': 'Toronto',
                 'Alberta': 'Edmonton',
                 'Manitoba': 'Winnipeg',
                 'Sasketchewan': 'Regina'
                 }
            }
     }
}
```

The most efficient method of solving this to my knowledge would be to use `for` loops to travel through the dictionary and fill out the pdf along the way. the end result would look arbitrarily like:

```
Begin PDF

Planet: 'Earth'
Section:'Northern Hemisphere'
Country: 'The United State of America'
SubCategory: 'California': 'Sacramento', 
             'Kentucky': 'Frankfurt', 
             'Colorado': 'Denver', 
             'Oregon': 'Salem', 
             'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 
             'Nevada': 'Carson City'

Planet: 'Earth'
Section: 'Northern Hemisphere'
Country: 'Canada'
SubCategory: 'Ontario': 'Toronto',
             'Alberta': 'Edmonton',
             'Manitoba': 'Winnipeg',
             'Sasketchewan': 'Regina'

End PDF
```

Formatting the PDF is not the problem I'm having, I have that figured out to some extent. My problem is understanding how to read this nested dictionary in a way that keys like `Northern Hemisphere` are understood to have two or more values attached to them, and keys such as `Earth` which only have one value, are understood to belong to both `Country` entries.

I hope I've made my problem clear, any help is appreciated.

Comment: No better way than a for loop, I'm afraid.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Ok thanks, so my only solution is to adequately structure a series of loops so that the information is extracted in the way I desire?

Comment: Maybe you can... give me a bit.

Comment: Okay, I was going to suggest using recursive regex with pyparsing but the trouble isn't worth the reward.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your help. I'm not opposed to having massive nested loops, I may be able to simplify the process later once I have a working model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: ... nested dictionary ... how do I ... extract ... in a sequential manner?

**Note**:
Your *Nested Dictionary* is close to `json`, why not using JSON?
Your given `dict` is **invalid**, *Country* `Canada` have to be inside *Section* `Northern Hemisphere`.

Recursive Solution, using `GeneratorType`.
The Output is a `dict` holding all Values from the given Keys in `keys`.

```
def Earth_nested_dict():
    keys = ['Planet',' Section', None, ' Country', 'SubCategory']
    _record = OrderedDict()

    def _nested_dict(_dict, key, deep):
        if isinstance(_dict, dict):
            if keys[deep]:
                _record[keys[deep]] = key
            for k in _dict:
                yield from _nested_dict(_dict[k], k, deep + 1)
        else:
            _record[keys[deep]] = '{}:{}'.format(key, _dict)
            yield _record

    yield from _nested_dict(nested_dict['Earth'], 'Earth', 0)
```

**Usage:**

```
for _record in Earth_nested_dict():
    print(_record)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> OrderedDict([('Planet', 'Earth'), (' Section', 'Northern Hemisphere'), (' Country', 'The United States of America'), ('SubCategory', 'Oregon:Salem')])
> ... (omitted for brevity)
> OrderedDict([('Planet', 'Earth'), (' Section', 'Northern Hemisphere'), (' Country', 'Canada'), ('SubCategory', 'Alberta:Edmonton')])
> ... (omitted for brevity)
> OrderedDict([('Planet', 'Earth'), (' Section', 'Southern Hemisphere'), (' Country', 'Brazil'), ('SubCategory', 'Bahia:Salvador')])
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Having abandoned my giant nested dictionary structure in favor of a less elegant (but easier to grok imo) series of nested loops this morning, I will accept this as answer as it does in fact solve the issue I was having. Thanks again for you help @stovfl